# Can I display messages from the server using node.js without templating?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, single-page-application, ejs, passport-local

Currently building a Single-page App with Node, with user authentication using passport and mongodb. I want to be able to send the user messages like "that username is already taken" or "please fill out all fields" on signup and login. However, all of the examples of this I have seen use a templating engine with a package like flash to render html based on javascript sent from the server. Is there a way around this? My app is pretty far along, and switching to a templating service is going to be a real pain. I don't need to render html, a simple alert box will suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create controller action that matches the route and manually pass found model to the view.

In UserController:

```
find: function(req, res) {
    User.findOne({'id': req.params['id']}, function(err, user) {
        res.view({user: user})
    })
}
```

Then You can reference this model in views/user/find.ejs:

```
<%- user.id %>
<%- user.name %>
```

use the above syntax to give alert();
I hope this is what you are looking for!